# Emacs lisp highlighting

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have wrote simple macro to define interactive function and bind it to key at same time
(That what my previous question related)
The only thing, that annoy me, that it looks ugly without highlighting.
It called such way:

```
(define-and-bind-command foo "C-x £" (message "Hello world"))
```

I want `define-and-bind-command` and `foo` be highlighted.
Well, to get `define-and-bind-command` highlighted, I can use wrapper around `defmacro`,
altho is not so pretty, and I have no idea about `foo`. 
I know it is possible, because argument of `require` is highlighted with const face.

Or, probably, I am inventing wheel, and there is an another lisp mode with more 
advanced highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

highlighting the 'define-and-bind-command' can be achieved very easily using 'font-lock-add-keywords', usage would be

```
(defun my-elisp-mode-keywords()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
    '(
      ("\\<\\(define-and-bind-command\\)" . 'font-lock-keyword-face)
    )
  )
)
```

Of course you could change the 'font-lock-keyword-face' to any face of your liking or create and use your own face. You can find the name for a face already used very easy by moving the point (cursor) over the font-locked part of text and entering 'describe-face' followed by a return.

**Edit2:** Oh and of course you need to hook that defun to some hook, for elisp mode that would be:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-elisp-mode-keywords)
```

Highlighting the foo part can be done using a regexp. 
<strike>Unfortunately I can not yet help you with that part because I'm not sure how to match a regexp containing the 'define-and-bind-command' but highlighting only the word after.</strike>
**Edit:** unless you want to highlight both the 'define-and-bind-command' and the foo part in the same face, then it should be very easy. But I guess you want them to have different faces?
**Edit3:** Corrected my code, stackoverflow ate some braces before...
**Edit4:** Okay, I have a solution for matching the second part only, I have not tested it extensively but it seems to work. I have allowed for foo to contains any character but a space (and newline I think), I guess one could restrict that event futher to a-zA-z0-9 and "-", so feel free to change that to your liking. The Code responsible for matching only the foo part is

```
("\\bdefine-and-bind-command\s\\([^\s]*\\)" 1 'font-lock-function-name-face t)
```

Insert that in the line after the other font-lock keyword in the above function and you're good to go. The regexp matches 'define-and-bind-command' which must begin a word (that's the **\b** for) followed by a space and then it returns (font-locks) everything followed until a space exists.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`font-lock-add-keywords` can take a symbol, the mode to which to apply the new keywords. So you could do

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '(("\\<\\(define-and-bind-command\\)" . 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

The disadvantage compared to using a function and a hook is that this doesn't work for derived modes; that is, if you have a mode which is derived from `emacs-lisp-mode`, it will not inherit these keywords.